# Window 10 Google chrome installation failed. No error code

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, installation

I just bought a dell laptop with window 10 and wanted to install chrome. Then it prompted me failed installation. Anyone has fix for this?

1. Tried remove Google registry - does not work
2. Run the installer as admin - does not work
3. Now updating my window 10.... hope it will work...

   [image]

Comment: there is a million possible reason... I had that several times and mostly it was a running background process that was trying to update my installation already. Make sure (Task Manager) that no other Chrome processes are running, or worst case reboot. For me that fixed all occurrences... it might or might not for you.

Comment: i checked task manager too. chrome was not running. further more this was a clean install